# Django:Filter entries of combobox in template to foreign key

Tags: django, templates

I am having trouble to find a solution to a problem of filtering entries of a combobox.
Just to make it easy to understand my problem here an ERM of my models:
[image: ERM]

and my Template looks like:
[image: Template]

Basicaly the queryset for this template is resulting of the following code:

```
class EquipmentinLocationAdd(CreateView):
    model = EquipmentInLocation
    form_class = EquipmentAddToLocationForm
    template_name = 'Procure/equipmentinlocation_add.html'
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('equipmentinlocation_sys', kwargs={'pk':self.object.Institute_id})
    def get_initial(self):
        qs = Institute.objects.get( id = self.kwargs['pk'] )
        initial = {'Institute': qs}
        return initial
```

Now I need to filter and restrict the entries of the combobox "Lot" only to the lots which belong to the same project as the institute.

However, bringing two queries together in one template seems to be a challenge hard to solve.

Need your help, please advise!!!

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way... The first thing that comes to mind

##### first, (I think it's most easily way)

1. django form just shows every Equipment options.
2. Javascript then handles the equipment selection visibility. (bind event 'change' to Lot select)
3. then django form validate 'Equipment' using form cleaning methods
   (whether the selected equipment is included in the selected lot)

##### Second,

1. Using asynchronous request (fetch, ajax, ...)
2. Refresh the choices from Response

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

May be this libraries can help you:

- [django-smart-selects](https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
  I don't personally use this library, but I think this is exactly what you want. Lib from famous `Jazz-band` group.
- also you can look at [django-admin-flexselect](https://github.com/runekaagaard/django-admin-flexselect). It's purposed for site-admin, but may be source code can give you some ideas.